# Reduce nested loops using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nested-loops

I was wandering if the following nested loops could be rewritten using linq. The catch here is that you return the "item2" if "value" is contained in a list of "item2".

```
foreach (var item1 in item1list)
    foreach (var item2 in item1.items2list)
        foreach (var item3 in item2.items3list)
            if (item3 == value)
                return item2;

return null;
```

Comment: So can I ask what you think Linq does that is any different from a series of loops?

Comment: @maccettura, it abstracts that away into well tested functional operators.

Comment: I believe that it doesn't, but using it makes the code more readable for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` for first 2 loops and `FirstOrDefault`+`Any` for the third + the if check:

```
return item1list.SelectMany(x1 => x1.items2list)
                .FirstOrDefault(x2 => x2.items3list.Any(x3 => x3 == value));
```

You could also replace the `Any` call with `Contains(value)`.

Is it more readable? Probably not. Putting your 3 loops in a private method with a descriptive name would probably be better for anybody who reads that code in the future.

Comment: Do you mean `x3 == value` (value instead of null)?